# RDLC Report Datasets/Tables and Custom Code

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

I've been given the task of updating some rdlc reports which I've never used before. Some of the more complex reports can have multiple datasets where each SQL query is over 10kb of text if copied to a text editor.  I'm finding it difficult to wrap my head around some of the more complex SQL.

I've found that I can add custom VB code to the report and I was thinking it would be nice if I could use a simpler query for the dataset and then do some processing with custom code that could populate an empty table in the report.  I haven't been able to find any examples of anything like this so I'm wondering if it's possible? If so, can anyone please give me a basic example of reading data from a dataset and adding rows to a table using custom code?

Thanks!

Comment: iirc you can also use a list of objects as a rdlc datasource. So you have a completely free hand as to the properties of your objects and the code you use to populate them.

Comment: Unfortunately the reports are used by another program that I have no control over. I can create the datasets and set the SQL for each dataset from within the other program but that's about it.